# Sorting on a column in removing html contents in Datatables 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatable

I am unsing datatable 1.10, In my code in one of the column as per the requirement I am adding an HTML checkbox tag.

**Now first time when the table gets rendered it shows me those checkboxes but when I click on that column to sort or any other column for sorting then the column which contains HTML contains are getting wiped out. (I crosschecked this with the chrome DOM inspector... the td element contains nothing :()**

Below is my dataTable initialization code.

```
dataTableOptions: function() {
            return {
                "orderable": true,
                "columnDefs": undefined,
                "autoWidth": true, 
                "deferRender": true, 
                "data": undefined
            };
        },
        dtRowGroupingOptions: function () {
            return {
                bExpandableGrouping: true,
                bExpandSingleGroup: false,
                iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
                asExpandedGroups: [""]
            };
        }

var dataTablesOptions = self.dataTableOptions();
                    dataTablesOptions.data = tableData;
                    dataTablesOptions["paginate"] = false;
                    dataTablesOptions["lengthChange"] = false;
                    dataTablesOptions["columnDefs"] = [{"targets": 0, "data": "serverName", 'title' : 'ServerName'},
                       {"targets": 1, "data": "COMMAND", 'title' : 'Command'},
                       {"targets": 2, "data": "PID", 'title' : 'Process Id'},
                       {"targets": 3, "data": "SIZE", 'title' : 'Size'},
                       {"targets": 4, "data": "USER", 'title' : 'User'},
                       {"targets": 5, "data": "action", 'title' : 'Actions', "type" : "html", "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"}
                       ];

                    dataTablesOptions["createdRow"] = function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                        var self = this;
                        if (aData["comments"] && aData["comments"].indexOf("Error") != -1) {
                            // Do not do anything 
                            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(aData["serverName"]+"" +
                            "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Error in execution'><i class='icon-question'></i></a>");
                        } 
                        return self;
                    };

var dcInfoDataTable = contentDiv.find('table.dcInfoTable').DataTable(dataTablesOptions);
```

I am also using datatables rowGrouping and searchhiglight plugin, below is the code.

```
// call row grouping
                    contentDiv.find('table.dcInfoTable').dataTable().rowGrouping(self.dtRowGroupingOptions());
                    // enable search highlighing
                    contentDiv.find('table.dcInfoTable').dataTable().fnSearchHighlighting();
```

**Note: I tried removing rowGrouping plugin code just to make sure that this is not happeing because of this plugin but even after removing there is no effect, the HTML contents are getting wiped out.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only when you sort will it clear out your data, it will also clear it if you use any other feature that changes your table.  This happens because each time the datatable draws for new data, it's clearing out your static data.

You need to re-append the checkboxes on each draw, you can do this in the [`fnDrawCallback`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) event:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
      //append the checkbox to your table columns here...
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Actually it worked with a little twick.... As I am using rowGrouping plugin i have to check the index of the cell before adding the value.